# File being used by another process in a Windows Service with a StreamReader

Tags: windows, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

I have searched numerous articles and tried several different ways of solving this issue.

**Note that this process works fine in a Console app or a Windows app with the exact same code. So, there's nothing wrong with the logic. It's the way the Windows Service is processing these files that is somehow not letting subsequent files get through.**

I tried reading a simple article to actually debug the service, but I don't have the "Attach To Process" selection under my Debug menu using Visual Studio 2010.
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.100).aspx**

I really need some help here, because my options have really run out.

Here is the simple scenario:
I have a FileSystemWatcher in the OnStart method that kicks off another method to process a file on my local machine. These are just simple txt files. When the first file is processed, everything is normal and I get the following in my Event log: 
Data successfully inserted for file **20121212_AZM_Journey_MIS.txt**

When I try and process subsequent files (exact same format, but a different name --- with the date), I get the following in my Event log:
The process cannot access the file **'C:\Projects\Data\VendingStats\20121213_AZM_Journey_MIS.txt'** because it is being used by another process.

Note that the files are watched for in this same directory when created.

Here is my code in my Windows Service. Can someone **please** let me know how I can solve this issue? Note that e.FullPath evaluates to "C:\Projects\Data\VendingStats" on my local machine.

```
    public partial class VendingStatsService : ServiceBase
        {

            public VendingStatsService()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Projects\Data\VendingStats");
                Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(**Watcher_Created**);
                Watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
                Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            }

private void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
                {
                    // code here to insert data from file into a DB
                }
                Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("VendorStats", "Error in the Main:" + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.InnerException);
                return;
            }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Comment: You can allways use system.diagonstic.debbugger.attach it prompt you to connect to a debugging session.

Comment: I tried a using statement System.Diagnostics. and no intellisense .debugger appearead. I'm not sure how you would debug the service based on what you said. I don't understand....

Comment: wrong thing System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() will launch a debugger I have used it to debug services before. You may have to switch the credentials to be under your user name.

Comment: This seems like a namespace. How does the debugger get launched? Do I need to add any references, etc?

Comment: did you try it. it pops up a dialogue box and you can select which ever version of VS you have the project loaded in.

Comment: I implemented it in my using statement, but I can't start to debug my service because of what I mentioned above: I tried reading a simple article to actually debug the service, but I don't have the "Attach To Process" selection under my Debug menu using Visual Studio 2010. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.100).aspx. How do you get your service to start debugging?